# Image inside dundas Gauge 1.5 ssrs 2005

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have some reports on ssrs 2005 that are using dundas 1.5 gauge cotrols. I am using Images inside this gauge control. It works fine on ssrs 2005 but When I migrate this Report to ssrs 2012 after conversion then this Image becomes disappear andI got empty values for this Image.

Here is the code snipt of this rdl that is from ssrs 2005.

```
 <CustomProperty>
        <Name>GaugeCore.NamedImages.0.NamedImage.Name</Name>
        <Value>orange.png</Value>
      </CustomProperty>
```

After converting this Report to ssrs 2012, I got

```
            <GaugeMajorTickMarks>
              <IntervalOffset>NaN</IntervalOffset>
              <Style>
                <Border>
                  <Color>DimGray</Color>
                  <Style>None</Style>
                </Border>
                <BackgroundColor>Black</BackgroundColor>
              </Style>
              <Placement>Cross</Placement>
              <EnableGradient>true</EnableGradient>
              <TickMarkImage>
                <Source>External</Source>
                <Value />
              </TickMarkImage>
              <Length>15</Length>
              <Width>2</Width>
            </GaugeMajorTickMarks>
            <GaugeMinorTickMarks>
              <IntervalOffset>NaN</IntervalOffset>
              <Style>
                <Border>
                  <Color>DimGray</Color>
                  <Style>None</Style>
                </Border>
                <BackgroundColor>Black</BackgroundColor>
              </Style>
              <Placement>Cross</Placement>
              <EnableGradient>true</EnableGradient>
              <TickMarkImage>
                <Source>External</Source>
                <Value />
              </TickMarkImage>
              <Length>3</Length>
              <Width>1.5</Width>
            </GaugeMinorTickMarks>
```

Please help me how to get rid of this issue, Otherwise I Need to re-work on these ssrs 2005 reports for proper functioning on ssrs 2012.